# Sort array inside a dict based on datetime

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x

I would like to sort my `versions` array based on the `modified_datetime` key. I can definitely use one of the sorting algorithms to do it but I'm just wondering if there is an efficient way to do it in Python.

```
my_json = {
  "versions": [
    {
      "migrated_versions": [ 
        {
          "modified_datetime": "2020-09-11T21:15:22.215Z"
        }
      ],
    },
    {
      "migrated_versions": [ 
        {
          "modified_datetime": "2020-09-11T21:14:19.162Z"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "migrated_versions": [ 
        {
          "modified_datetime": "2020-09-11T21:10:19.289Z"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the datetimes are ISO8601, which is lexicographically sortable, you can just use the `sorted()` built-in (or `list.sort()`) with the `key=` argument:

```
sorted(my_json["versions"], key=lambda v: v["migrated_versions"][0]["modified_datetime"])
```